# Meaning of mosaic in a particular context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The meaning of the word **mosaic** that I am getting on Goolge is

First meaning is

*a picture or pattern produced by arranging together small colored pieces of hard material, such as stone, tile, or glass*

and the second meaning is

*an individual (especially an animal) composed of cells of two genetically different types*

I need to understand the meaning of the words - **mosaic cropland, mosaic grassland, mosaic vegetation**. But I am not able to see what does these words can mean if I use the above-mentioned meaning of mosaic. So, can someone please explain to me the meaning of **mosaic** in the context of given three words?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the tiled appearance of some fields etc that's suggestive of the signature look of mosaics (using the first meaning of *mosaic* in your question).

Comment: Try a different dictionary. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mosaic) lists these three senses first:  << **mosaic**
1
:  a surface decoration made by inlaying small pieces of variously colored material to form pictures or patterns; also :  the process of making it
2
:  a picture or design made in mosaic
3
:  something resembling a mosaic  (sense 1.) ... >> and [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mosaic) gives senses : <<2. A composite picture made of overlapping, usually aerial, photographs.
3. Something that resembles a mosaic >>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Biology Online](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Mosaic) gives these definitions:

> (1) A pattern consisting of numerous small pieces (or elements) fitted together.
>
> (2) Anything that resembles such a pattern, as in fluid mosaic model of cell membranes.
>
> (genetics) Mosaicism, or the organism exhibiting mosaicism, which is the occurrence of two or more cell populations with different genotypes in an individual.
>
> (botany) A mosaic disease: a viral disease of ornamental and crop plants characterized by mottling and discoloration of leaves.
>
> **(ecology) A habitat mosaic: a pattern of interspersed ecosystem of similar size and on a recurring basis.**
>
> Supplement
>
> In genetics, a mosaic or mosaicism refers to the presence of two (or more) populations of cells, each with different genotypes in an individual. It may be a gonadal mosaicism or tissue mosaicism. An example of mosaicism is 46/47 XY/XXY mosaic.

I've put the part you need in bold.

The basic idea is that if you look at the landscape from a big distance, it will somewhat resemble a mosaic tiled floor.

Example:

[image: mosaic cropland]

Answer (score 1):

> [Cropland Mosaics](https://mynasadata.larc.nasa.gov/glossary/cropland-mosaics-ceressarb-2/)(CERES/SARB) [(Images)](https://www.google.co.in/#q=cropland+mosaic&*) , [Grassland](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Experiments/Biome/biograssland.php), [Vegetation](https://ldas.gsfc.nasa.gov/gldas/GLDASmapveg.php)
>
> Cropland mosaics is closely related to the Surface Scene Type
>   parameter. Scientists have classified regions of the world into
>   different types of surface cover. In the LAS, there are [18 different
>   surface type categories](https://mynasadata.larc.nasa.gov/ceres-surface-type-data/). These categories have been defined by the
>   CERES team. These 18 categories provide a “snapshot” overview of what
>   the land surface is like in that area. These parameters can be used to
>   investigate patterns in other Earth science parameters, and how they
>   are related to environment and surface cover.